# Buffer.Copy RangeError

Tags: node.js, buffer

This piece of code produces the following sample output:

```
buf = new Buffer( end - start );

console.log(buf.length);
console.log(data.length);
console.log(start);
console.log(end);

data.copy( buf, 0, start, end );
```

Fist call:

```
3732395 // buf.len
3732395 // data.len
0       // start
3732395 // end
```

Second call:

```
29611   // buf.len
3732395 // data.len
3702784 // start
3732395 // end

RangeError: sourceEnd < sourceStart
    at Buffer.copy [..]
```

It seems that all the parameters are fine. Especially the start and end values don't fulfill the error message.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of node are you using?  At 0.10.24, the error you seem to be hitting has the text `sourceEnd < sourceStart`, which would be an actual error condition - note the `<`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it was just a stupid typo. I'm currently on  `v0.10.28`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly I passed `strings` as parameters which did not yield the desired result.
This call inside `Buffer.copy` (`v0.10.28`) appends `this.offset` to my strings causing the error to be thrown.

```
return this.parent.copy(target.parent || target,
                        target_start + (target.offset || 0),
                        start + this.offset,
                        end + this.offset);
```